# Keep the identifier for each row in a rolling window of functions R

Tags: r, lapply, accelerometer, rbind, rollapply

I have managed to apply a rolling window of functions per column of my accelerometer data where each row is associated with a behaviour. However, the output doesn't include the behaviour associated. Is there a way to either keep the behaviour per window in the dataset OR apply the behaviour associated to the rownames.

```
    df1 <- read.table(text = "
Time    X_accel  y_accel   Behaviour
1   0.01  0.1  Standing
2   0.01  0.2  Standing
3   0.01  0.2  Standing
4   0.02  0.1  Standing
5   0.06  0.8  Walking
6   0.07   0.8 Walking
7   0.01  0.2  Standing
8   0.02  0.2  Standing
9   0.01  0.1  Standing
10  0.9   0.95 Flying            
11  0.95  0.99 Flying
12  0.9   0.95 Flying",
                  header = TRUE)

# Sampling interval (Hz)
sampling.interval = 2
# Duration of epoch required (seconds)
duration = 1
# Window step required (0-1: percentage to move forward)
step = 0.1
# Set window size for rolling windows
window.size = sampling.interval*duration
# Set step size for rolling windows
window.step = step*window.size
####

time_domain_summary <- function(values) {
  
  features <- data.frame(
    mean = mean(values, na.rm = TRUE),
    median = quantile(values, probs = c(0.5), na.rm = TRUE), 
    mx =  max(values, na.rm = T),
    mn = min(values, na.rm = T), 
    sd = sd(values),
    range = max(values, na.rm = T) - min(values, na.rm = T)
    
  )
  return(features)
}  

f <- cumsum(c(0, df1$Behaviour[-1] != df1$Behaviour[-nrow(df1)]))

list <- by(df1[,c(2:3)], f, \(x, fill) {
  rollapply(x, FUN = time_domain_summary, width = window.size, by = window.step,  align = c("left"), partial = FALSE) 
  }, fill = NA)

df2 <- do.call(rbind, lapply(list, data.frame))

colnames(df2) <- c("x_mean", "x_median", "x_mx", "x_mn", "x_sd", "x_range", "y_mean", "y_median", "y_mx", "y_mn", "y_sd", "y_range")
```

Output = df2

I would like EITHER labelled in the rownames as: 0.1-0.3 "standing", 1 "Walking", 2.1 - 2.2 "Standing, 3.1-3.2 "Flying" and so on OR to have an extra column that includes the associated behaviour. This is a simple example - the actual dataset has 10000s of rows and behaviours which last varying amounts of time, anything less than the set window will be discounted in the output. I'm looking of a way to identify the output rows by the behaviour associated with them in df1 (regardless of size of dataset) if possible.

Comment: Row names cannot repeat, so labeling all within `0.1-0.3` as `"standing"` is a non-starter, you need to add it as a new column. For that, perhaps `cut(as.numeric(rownames(df2)), c(-1, 0.9, 2, 3, 4), labels = c("standing", "Walking", "Standing", "Flying"))`

Comment: That works beautifully on my simple example dataframe thankyou! I'm struggling to understand what the c(-1, 0.9, 2, 3, 4) is here - are these the breaks based on the "rowname" values? My actual dataset is 60 columns wide and 10,000+ rows long and will discound any behaviours les than a 10s window so I wouldn't necessarily know the values in the "rownames" bit to apply manual breaks to them (if I've understood correctly)

Comment: Yes, those are used for binning them. In this case, you explicitly set them in the last paragraph of your question, so I assumed they were meaningful bins. I'm not really following the nuances of `width = window.size, by = window.step` (I understand the _premise_) with this data, so I don't know that I can really advise (now) on how to generalize.

Comment: Sorry, lack of clarity on my part the window sizes and step are only set up like that so they can be changed on the larger data sets (I'll need to run with multiple different window sizes, and levels of overlap) not 100% if that is the best way but I'm looking of a way to identify the output rows by the behaviour associated with them in df1 (regardless of size). I'll add this to the original Q if that helps.